# Filter list of object by value of property of nested list equals value of same property of another element of the nested list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

Ok, I have this class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SpecialNumber { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Game> Games { get; set; }
}
```

And these classes:

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? RamNeeded { get; set; }
    public Town Town { get; set; }
}

public class Town
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string TownName { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display the `SpecialNumber` of the `Person`, whose ***Sum*** of games' `RamNeeded` is greatest, from People (`IQueryable<Person>`), who have games:

1. From more than 2 different ***Towns*** in one ***State***.
2. From different ***States*** in one ***Country***(This means that there are at least two games with different States).
3. From different ***Countries*** (This means that there are at least two games with different Countries).

I need to make this query on LINQ or SQL. Hope you can help.

Comment: What's the part causing you difficulty?

Comment: (1), (2), (3) are filter criteria, correct? How they are combined - `AND` or `OR`?

Comment: @DanBracuk How to compare the values of the Towns names in LINQ in first place

Comment: @IvanStoev  Yes, they are combined as AND

Answer (score 0):

Anytime you need to do something with the elements of a set that have equal value of some property, you can use [GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534492(v=vs.110).aspx) method (or [group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384063.aspx) clause in query syntax).

Then you can use different aggregate functions for each group of elements. For instance, in your case [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb468851(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to check if the group contains a specific amount of items.

With that being said, the query in question could be something like this

```
IQueryable<Person> persons = ...;

var query =
    from person in persons
    let countryGroups = person.Games.GroupBy(game => game.Town.CountryName)
    where countryGroups.Count() > 1 // (3)
        && countryGroups.Any(countryGroup =>
            countryGroup.GroupBy(game => game.Town.StateName).Count() > 1 // (2)
            && countryGroup.GroupBy(game => game.Town.StateName).Any(stateGroup =>
                stateGroup.GroupBy(game => game.Town.Id).Count() > 2)) // (1)
    let RamNeeded = person.Games.Sum(game => game.RamNeeded) // in case you need to include it in the select
    orderby RamNeeded descending
    select person.SpecialNumber;

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```